# Graph problem approach or solution needed

Tags: algorithm

Given a matrix (dimensions= m X n)of Strings (“X” and “0”) where “X” represents students who are not interested in playing at all and “O” represents the students who are interested in chess. find the maximum possible number of chess games that can take place at the same time in the class.
We have to make pairs of adjacent chess player. Diagonal pairs are not considered.

eg 1:
3 3

O O O

O X X

X X X
ans = 2

eg2:
4 5

O O O O O

O O O O O

O X X O O

O O O O O
ans = 9

Eg: 3
2 3

X O X

O O O

ans=1

Comment: A related problem (covering the grid with 2x2 blocks instead of 2x1) is NP-complete (http://cccg.ca/proceedings/2009/cccg09_09.pdf). You have one more degree of freedom (2x1 blocks can be rotated), so it seems likely to me that this problem is NP-hard too. That would mean you just need to brute-force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, I don't see a better approach than brute-forcing this. I would iterate the grid from top-left to bottom-right and in each empty cell try one of the three options (horizontal block, vertical block, leave empty), and then solve the rest of the grid recursively.

If the size of the grids is not crazy large you can solve this with recursion. If that leads to a stack overflow you would need to use a custom stack instead.

```js
function solve(grid, x = 0, y = 0) {
  // find first next empty cell
  while (y < grid.length && (x >= grid[y].length || grid[y][x] !== 'O')) {
    x++; // step to the right
    if (x >= grid[y].length) {
      // if we stepped out of the grid, go the next row
      x = 0;
      y++;
    }
  }

  // reached end of grid
  if (y >= grid.length) {
    return 0;
  }

  // three options:
  // - skip this cell
  // - put a horizontal block
  // - put a vertical block

  // skip this cell
  const results = [solve(grid, x + 1, y)];

  // put horizontal block
  if (x + 1 < grid[0].length && grid[y][x + 1] === 'O') {
    // step to (x+2, y) because (x+1, y) is already occupied
    results.push(solve(grid, x + 2, y) + 1);
  }

  // put vertical block
  if (y + 1 < grid.length && grid[y + 1][x] === 'O') {
    // mark (x, y+1) so we won't be able to use it once we reach that cell
    grid[y + 1][x] = '*'

    results.push(solve(grid, x + 1, y) + 1);

    // clear (x, y+1)
    grid[y + 1][x] = 'O'
  }

  return Math.max(...results);
}

console.log(solve([
  ['O', 'O', 'O'],
  ['O', 'X', 'X'],
  ['X', 'X', 'X']
]));
console.log(solve([
  ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
  ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
  ['O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O'],
  ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
]));
console.log(solve([
  ['X', 'O', 'X'],
  ['O', 'O', 'O']
]));
```